# Real time notification without reloading

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, pusher

I am building some reminders on my system. A user can create reminders that will show an alert when is time to remind something to the user.

I'd like to know how to display an alert without reloading. I want to show this alert when `remindTime = now`.

Migration:

```php
 Schema::create('reminders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('description', 255);
    $table->dateTime('remindTime');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Function from where I fetch only reminders who will be comming after 3 hours from now:

```php
$latestReminder = Reminder::where('remindTime', '<=', Carbon::now()->addHours(3)->toDateTimeString())
    ->where('remindTime', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
    ->latest()
    ->take(3)
    ->get()
;
```

How I fetch on vue:

```
getReminders() {
  axios.get('/reminders/get-reminders')
    .then(response => {
      this.reminders = response.data.data
    })
  },
}
```

Comment: Look into something called 'echo'. It's delivered with a default laravel installation. I would go for an event, whenever the event is fired, echo is listening for it and displaying those reminders

Comment: @UnderDog I dont understand this. I have seen a lot tutorial with pusher but not understand very wel